# Truncating memory mapped file

Tags: c, ios, mmap

I would like to use a read/write memory mapped file to manage some indexes (`unsigned int`) I'm creating.

I've followed the code examples found [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/mmap-tutorial-c-c-511265/) and [here](http://memfrag.se/blog/Memory-Mapped-Files)

I don't know the size of the file initially, so I plan on making it about 4K to start with and grow accordingly.

However, I'm unsure how to truncate the file once I'm done with the map.  So if I only use about 1K in the file, I would like to truncate it to 1K and not waste 3K in the process.  My concern is not specifically with wasting file space, but rather I check the size of the file to determine how many `unsigned int` I have.

**EDIT**

So to clarify...while the file is memory mapped...I'm allocating 4K chunks...when I'm done with the memory mapped file, I want to cleanup the file so it is exactly what I've put into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ftruncate` to truncate your file, it just requires the file descriptor and a size. Then later you can use `fstat` to query the properties of the underlying file and use the size you obtain from there to dimension future mappings.

Comment: Is that thread-safe? If `ftruncate` a file while another thread is using it?

Answer (score 2):

If you ftruncate() the file, you'll have to "simultaneously" mremap() the mapping to the new size. You can do a similar thing for extents (but that may cause mremap to place the segment in a different part of your address space)

Comment: I think mremap() isn't a standard function...so I just munmap() then mmap()...at any rate, ftruncate() works for me...

Comment: You're right. It is not in POSIX. Linux has it, True64/OSF had it. BSD seems to have one with different semantics. But: if it is present, it is probably cheaper than a munmap() + mmap() combo.

Comment: This is not necessary. You can `mmap` more than the actual size of the file, and writing more than a page past the end of the file will result in `SIGBUS`. If you increase the size with `ftruncate` before writing, you should have no problem, though.

Comment: That is just a way of implementing what I called "simultaneously". It gets harder if you have to juggle with more than one mmap()ed area: the signalhandler (or something invoked by it) has to find out which of the areas caused the fault.

Answer (score -1):

When you try to optimize, use the value that getpagesize() returns. That is the standard system memory page size, no need to truncate it.

Comment: I clarified my question...my intention is not to truncate while the file is memory mapped...but rather after I'm done with the file...

Comment: It is similar for the filesystem. Check the file block size for your system, I think it's 4 kB or even more.

Comment: Right...I understand that files have a block size, but as I mention in my question I check the size of the file to determine how many unsigned ints I have.  As an aside, I found that getpagesize() is deprecated.